# Scikit-learn SequentialFeatureSelector Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). even with pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm trying to use SequentialFeatureSelector and for `estimator` parameter I'm passing it a pipeline that includes a step that inputes the missing values:

```
model = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessing',
                 ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('pipeline-1',
                                                  Pipeline(steps=[('imputing',
                                                                   SimpleImputer(fill_value=-1,
                                                                                 strategy='constant')),
                                                                  ('preprocessing',
                                                                   StandardScaler())]),
                                                  <sklearn.compose._column_transformer.make_column_selector object at 0x1300013d0>),
                                                 ('pipeline-2',
                                                  Pipeline(steps=[('imputing',
                                                                   SimpleImputer(fill_value='missing',
                                                                                 strategy='constant')),
                                                                  ('encoding',
                                                                   OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))]),
                                                  <sklearn.compose._column_transformer.make_column_selector object at 0x1300015b0>)])),
                ('model',
                 LGBMClassifier(class_weight='balanced', random_state=1,
                                reg_lambda=0.1))])
```

Nonetheless when passing this to selector it shows an error, what does not make any sense since I have already fit and evaluated my model and it runs ok

```
fselector = SequentialFeatureSelector(estimator = model, scoring= "roc_auc", cv = 3, n_jobs= -1, ).fit(X, target)




 _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
        101                 not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
        102             type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
    --> 103             raise ValueError(
        104                     msg_err.format
        105                     (type_err,
    
    ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

**EDIT:**

Reproducible example:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y = True)
X[:10,0] = np.NaN

clf = Pipeline([("preprocessing", SimpleImputer(missing_values= np.NaN)),("model",LogisticRegression(random_state = 1))])                                                                        

SequentialFeatureSelector(estimator = clf,
                           scoring= "accuracy",
                           cv = 3).fit(X, y)
```

It shows the same error, in spite of the `clf` can be fit without problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ScikitLearn's documentation does not state that the SequentialFeatureSelector works with pipeline objects. It only [states](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SequentialFeatureSelector.html) that the class accepts an unfitted estimator. In view of this, you could remove the classifier from your pipeline, preprocess X, and then pass it along with an unfitted classifier for feature selection as shown in the example below.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import MaxAbsScaler


X, y = load_iris(return_X_y = True)
X[:10,0] = np.NaN

pipe = Pipeline([("preprocessing", SimpleImputer(missing_values= np.NaN)),
                ('scaler', MaxAbsScaler())])


# Preprocess your data
X = pipe.fit_transform(X)

# Run the SequentialFeatureSelector
sfs = SequentialFeatureSelector(estimator = LogisticRegression(),
                           scoring= "accuracy",
                           cv = 3).fit(X, y)

# Check which features are important and transform X
sfs.get_support()
X = sfs.transform(X)
```

Comment: In such way your model will be biased, because you are preprocessing all the dataset before splitting in cv folds

Comment: The Sequential Feature Selector is used to select features based on their importance, not to do predictions.

Comment: But the difference with other sklearn feature selection wrapper, like rfe, is that SFS calcultate importance according to the delta scores between models with and without features. So yes, it makes predictions.

Comment: Quoting from the documentation: This Sequential Feature Selector adds (forward selection) or removes (backward selection) features to form a feature subset in a greedy fashion. At each stage, this estimator chooses the best feature to add or remove based on the cross-validation score of an estimator. This is not the same as having a data set, splitting it in a training and test set and doing the whole predictive work flow. The OP has the freedom to just see which features are important for LR or whether to transform the data set as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SequentialFeatureSelection from mlxtend package
https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/

```
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import numpy as np

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y = True)
X[:10,0] = np.NaN

clf = Pipeline([
    ("preprocessing", SimpleImputer(missing_values= np.NaN)),
    ("model",LogisticRegression(random_state = 1))
])

sfs = SequentialFeatureSelector(estimator = clf, 
                                forward = True, 
                                k_features = 'best', 
                                scoring = "accuracy", 
                                cv = 3, n_jobs=-1).fit(X, y)
sfs.k_feature_idx_

>>> (0, 1, 2, 3)
```